# Are possibly rude comments allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

Someone made [a comment on my answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333567/is-it-mutual-causation-or-mutual-causality#comment633153_333715) saying:

> Very poor answer tbh of a new contributor bounty hunting.

Would this be allowed? I don't think this is the purpose for commenting, so I flagged it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not the [purpose of comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

The author of the comments is free to think it's a poor answer and downvote it, but that's not what comments are for, and (perhaps depending on your point of view) slightly over the line. Thanks for flagging, it has been removed.